# How to create a header that has a changing set of values

Tags: header-footer

The Liber Usualis (a book of music) has a header format that I would like to copy without having to specify each page seperately.

The format is roughly: `{month} {days.join(", ")}`

[image]

Where `days` is the set of sections that are present on the page.

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you make a small document that illustrates how your sections are given? Please give it as an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that)

Comment: It is not clear, where the data for the days comes from. It must be collected somewhere, right?

Comment: Yeah, I have headers for each of the days already defined. I was hoping there is some way to declare that a section starts and ends and have latex generate these sorts of headers.